# Move existing div into another div with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

After selecting an option from first dropdown list then another dropdown list appear according to selected option. When an option is selected from the second one then the selected one's value is sent to **input element** that is at the top of the page as hidden. It also calls function "bolumGonder" which submits form that includes **input element** to same page with GET method. Then according to GET variable retrieve some data from database.
PHP

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_GET['bolumtani']) && !empty($_GET['bolumtani'])) {
    include_once 'alinabilendersler.php';
}   
?>

HTML

<script>    
    function bolumGonder() {
        var seciliBolum = $(".insaat").val();
        if ( seciliBolum.length > 0 ) {
            $("#bolumtani").val(seciliBolum);
            document.bolumtaniform.submit();
        }       
    }
</script>
<form name="bolumtaniform" action="program.php" method="GET">   
    <input name="bolumtani" id="bolumtani" type="text" style="display:none" />
</form>

<div id="orta_div">
    <select class="fakulte_sec" onclick = "bolumAc()">
        <option selected>Fakülte</option>
        <option value="insaat">İnşaat Fakültesi</option>
        <option value="mimarlik">Mimarlık Fakültesi</option>
        <option>Makina Fakültesi</option>
        <option>Uçak ve Uzay Bilimleri Fakültesi</option>
    </select>

    <select class="insaat" style="display:none" onchange="bolumGonder()">
        <option value="" selected>Bölüm</option>
        <option value="ins">İnşaat Mühendisliği %30</option>
        <option value="inse">İnşaat Mühendisliği %100</option>
        <option>Çevre Mühendisliği %30</option>
        <option>Çevre Mühendisliği %100</option>
    </select>

    <select class="mimarlik" style="display:none">
        <option>Mimarlık %30</option>
        <option>İnşaat Mühendisliği %100</option>
        <option>Çevre Mühendisliği %30</option>
        <option>Çevre Mühendisliği %100</option>
    </select>
    <div class="uygun_dersler_ana_div" style="width:100%; color: white; height: 1500px;position: absolute ;overflow: hidden"><?php if (isset($_GET['bolumtani']) && !empty($_GET['bolumtani'])) {$sonuc = bolum($_GET['bolumtani']);} else {}?></div>

</div>
```

Gettin data from MySQL

```
<?php
##Database Bağlantısı##
$host = 'host';
$user = 'username';
$pass = 'password';
$db = 'databasename';

$baglan = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db);

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'  ");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
mysql_query("SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8_turkish_ci' ");


## Her Ders İçin Ayrı Tablo Oluştur ##            

function bolum($degisken) {
    # Ders Kodlarını Al # # Gets Class Name From Another Website, Asign them into an array ##
    $ch = curl_init("someURL");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $cl = curl_exec($ch);
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($cl);
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

    $derskodlari = $xpath->query("//option[position() >1]");
    $todbderskodlariarr = array();
    foreach ($derskodlari as $derskodu) {
        $todbderskodlariarr[] = $derskodu;
    }

    $todbderskodu = array();

    foreach ($todbderskodlariarr as $todbderskoduarr) {
        $todbderskodu[] = $todbderskoduarr->nodeValue;
    }

    ## This is just an exception. ##
    $todbderskodu[81] = "MODD";

    for ($a = 0; $a < count($todbderskodu); $a++) {
        @$todbderskodu[$a] = mysql_query("SELECt crnler, derskodu, gun, bina, dersadi FROM $todbderskodu[$a] WHERE dersialabilen LIKE '%" . $bolum . "%'");
    }

    $a = 0;
    while ($a < count($todbderskodu)) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($todbderskodu[$a], MYSQL_NUM)) {
            $class = substr($row[1], 0, 3);
            echo '<div class="' . $class . '" id="' . $row[0] . '">' . $row[4] . $row[0] . '&nbsp; |' . $row[2] . '</div>';
        }
        echo '<br>';
        $a = $a + 1;
    }
}
?>
```

Upto now everything works perfect. Script creates divs that have class AKM,ALM,ATA,UCK.. etc.  I want to put all divs that have same class into classname_main_div. How can i do that?

Comment: Please expand on what you mean with 'same class'?

Comment: Clone those divs and append them to the classname_main_div prior to removing them from the DOM in their original locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the class of the looped divs and append to the other div like:

```
$(".looped-divs").appendTo(".container-div");
```

Hope that helps
cheers!

PD: remember to scape the GET variables to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Thanks a lot. But one more question. I've created 114 divs with PHP for loop. In order to move divs into another existing div i should use Javascript. But i get divs classes' names from another website thanks to PHP. But as i know i can't do that with Js. Do i have to write all 114 divs classes' name one by one into Js array then make for loop ? or there is some Js method i can use to get items of PHP array? 
I hope I could explain my problem.

Comment: it deppends of the name of the class...if you have tottaly random names you will have to use the container div to select the items inside of it, like this:
assuming that looped div contains a list of divs that you whant to move
`$(".looped-divs div")`

also you can use the "starting with" selector.
only if the div class starts with "x" value:
`$("div[class^='item-']")`
there you geting all the divs that have a class starting with the word "item".
there is a lot of ways to do it.
i recomend you to use your browser developer console to see if you are selecting all the divs you want.
cheers!